# Como ajustar margens no R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, rmarkdown

Estou criando um documento no R Markdown, mas quando vou gerar o markdown ele ocupa toda a área do navegador, ficando ruim a leitura. Gostaria de saber como ajustar as margens, para que ele crie uma barra de rolagem, mas respeitando um espaço de margem à direita e à esquerda.

[image: down]

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 1):

Inclua abaixo do YAML o código abaixo (O YAML é o cabeçalho do RMarkdown):

```
<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```